# Golang: go build failing when called as part of makefile

Tags: go, docker

I have the following make file:

```
default: builddocker

setup:
     go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
     go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
     go get golang.org/x/net/context
     go get google.golang.org/grpc

buildgo:
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags "-s" -a -installsuffix cgo -o main ./customer-server/

builddocker:
                    docker build -t johnwesonga/grpc/customer-server -f ./Dockerfile.build .
                    docker run -t johnwesonga/grpc/customer-server /bin/true
                    docker cp `docker ps -q -n=1`:/main .
                    chmod 755 ./main
                    docker build --rm=true --tag=johnwesonga/grpc/customer-server -f Dockerfile.static .
```

My Dockerfile.build has:

```
FROM golang

ADD Makefile /
WORKDIR /
RUN make setup

RUN make buildgo
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But every time I run "make builddocker" I get the following error:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags "-s" -a -installsuffix cgo -o main ./customer-server/
can't load package: package ./customer-server: open /customer-server: no such file or directory
make: *** [buildgo] Error 1
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'buildgo' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c make buildgo' returned a non-zero code: 2
make: *** [builddocker] Error 2
```

But if I run "Make buildgo" it works just fine, any idea why this is failing?

FYI my source tree as follows:

```
/go/src/github.com/johnwesonga/grpc/MakeFile
/go/src/github.com/johnwesonga/grpc/customer-server
/go/src/github.com/johnwesonga/grpc/customer-server/main.go
```

Comment: Looks like you are adding the Makefile but not the `customer-server` directory to the image. Does that come from somewhere else?

Comment: customer-server is a directory containing my go code

Comment: I understand that, what I'm saying is it doesn't look like you're copying it into the container or mounting it as a volume. Your code is never in the same place as the Makefile. That's what the error message is saying, there's nothing to compile inside the container.

Comment: Add a `find / -print` to your buildgo step to see what's available in the container. R0MANARMY is correct.